# Java Window Selection or Focus

Tags: java

Java - Window Selection/Focus
Is there anyway of doing this in Java?  The client i was using was written is pascal I believe
I does stuff like this
[image]

Comment: Have you read [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) in the Java tutorials?

Comment: What are you referring to, having a navigation panel? Having a panel outlined when it has focus? What have you tried? Please be more specific and post what you don't understand

Comment: The picture I took wasn't a very good example.  But it works anywhere on the screen.  I guess I can always make a rectangle and have the Robot class focus there.

Comment: I'll take another picture to show you guys more.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/feWfk58.png

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just going to have the users make a rectangle for the focus area.